# How to cancel closing winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

When closing form, `FormClosed` event occurs, and I want to put some work when `FormClosed` event occurs like:

```
this.FormClosed += (s, e) => {
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Exit Program?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcons.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.No) {
        return;
    } else {
        // Do some work such as closing connection with sqlite3 DB
        Application.Exit();
    }
};
```

The problem is that no matter I choose yes or no in the messagebox, the program gets closed. I need to abort program exit if I choose no, so how do I do that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `FormClosing` (as opposed to your `FormClosed`) event's `FormClosingEventArgs` contains a `Cancel` boolean that you can change to true. Note that this will occur even if you close the form programmatically.

```
this.FormClosing += (s, e) => {
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Exit Program?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcons.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.No) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    } else {
        // Do some work such as closing connection with sqlite3 DB
        Application.Exit();
    }
};
```

To determine how the form was closed, it also includes a `CloseReason`.
See docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Mind that OP is using `FormClosed` and you are suggesting to use `FormClosing`. This could be stated a bit more prominently.

Comment: @Fildor Noted :)

Comment: isnt FormClosed too late to ask user?

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, it is.

Comment: Too fast for me :-) +1

Comment: I don't matter whether I use `FormClosed` or `FormClosing`. : ) Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Fedrik Mind that john is in fact suggesting to use FormClos**ing** event instead of FormClos**ed**.

Comment: @GreenRoof If this answer solves your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Forgot. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the `FormClosed` event, you need to use the `FormClosing` event and set `e.Cancel` to `true`.

The reason for that is that the `FormClosed` event occurs after the form has been closed, while the `FormClosing` event occurs as the form is being closed.

The `FormClosingEventArgs` class contains a boolean property called `Cancel` that you can set to `true` to stop the form from being closed.